# Can I download only partial part of Internet web page using lxml?

Tags: python, web, lxml

I'm not sure if this is possible and lxml documentation is not very good to me.

Can I for example use something like:

```
import lxml.html as lx
x = lx.parse('http://web.info/page.html')
y = x.xpath('\\something\interesting'[2])
```

or similar, so that I don't download whole page?

If not with lxml is there some Python module that can do this?

Comment: How would you logically define the length of the partial (required) part of the html? by tag? by number of characters?

Comment: I don't know the internals that's why I asked. I was imagining some lxml magic to download only `y` or xpath expression while `x` or base address does not need necessarily to be downloaded. I guess I expected too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: `lxml` has to parse the whole page before it can be guaranteed to find an individual bit of it, and to parse it the whole page, it obviously has to download the whole page. (But see also unutbu’s answer for a potential partial downloading/parsing approach.)

And although I believe one can make HTTP requests for part of a file (I think via the `range` header?), that’s not guaranteed to be supported on the server side.

It’s a shame that HTTP doesn’t include a method for sending an XPath query to the server along with the page request, and have the results of running that query on the page sent back.

Comment: @zetah: no problem. Props to [unutbu’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786979/can-i-download-only-partial-part-of-internet-web-page-using-lxml/7787089#7787089) though, I hadn’t realised `range`, or parsing part of an HTML page, was a reliable option. Might well be worth a try if you‘re very bandwidth-constrained.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [incremental parsing](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#incremental-parsing):

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as LH

# request a partial download
url='http://www.python.org/'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (0, 1024)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content=f.read()
# print(content)

# incremental parsing
parser=LH.HTMLParser()
parser.feed(content)
x = parser.close()
y = x.xpath('//link')
print(y)
```

yields

```
[<Element link at 9dc5aac>, <Element link at 9dc5adc>, <Element link at 9dc5b0c>]
```

Comment: Interesting... thanks. I guess `urllib` can also handle limited range just like `urllib2`, or is it handled by `lxml`?